# Laravel 4 - A four digit year could not be found Data missing

Tags: database, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent, updates

I'm trying to update some data and I'm having the next message:

```
A four digit year could not be found Data missing
```

In this form, I have some data that I want to update in my 'Actividad', so I have created an array with every field I need to update.

But, one of the form fields, I don't want to put it in the same array, because I need it to update the data in a pivot table ('actividad_material').

By the moment, I'm not able to update any of them... :(

Here is my code:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = array(
        'titulo' => Input::get('titulo'),
        'actividad' => Input::get('actividad'),
        'datos' => Input::get('datos'),
        'solucion' => Input::get('solucion'),
        'minutos' => Input::get('minutos'),
        'tipo_id' => Input::get('tipo_id'),
        'asignatura_id' => Input::get('asignatura_id'),
        'bloque_id' => Input::get('bloque_id'),
        'contenido_id' => Input::get('contenido_id'),
        'objetivo_id' => Input::get('objetivo_id'),
        'nivel_id' => Input::get('nivel_id'),
        'etapa_id' => Input::get('etapa_id'),
        'm_desc' => Input::get('m_desc'),
        'slug' => Str::slug(Input::get('titulo')),
        'user_id' => Sentry::getUser()->id,
        '_method'
        );

    $v = Validator::make($input, Actividad::$rules);

    if($v->passes())
    {
         // Trying to update my pivot table...
         $actividad = Actividad::find($id);
         $material_id = array(
            'material_id' => Input::get('material_id'));            
         $actividad->materials->sync($material_id);

        Actividad::find($id)->update($input);

        return Redirect::route('actividads.index');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v);
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error? Maybe the timestamps?

What am I doing wrong when updating?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Get rid of that `_method` in your `$input` array.

Comment: Thank you @deczo! You're the number one!!! XD

Comment: Now I'm trying to update my pivot table and I'm getting the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sync() ` Any idea what happens with 'sync()'?

Comment: You need to use relation methods on relation objects: `$model->relation; // related model or collection` while `$model->relation(); // Relation object`. Meaning, remember parentheses!